# Not able to run oracle sql developer?

Tags: java, oracle

I stated the path directing to java 8 during first run of oracle sql developer.But it is not supporting it.
So my question is how to change the JAVAhome path to java 6 in sqldeveloper.config??

Answer (score 2):

Open `${user.home}/.sqldeveloper/${sqldeveloper.version}/product.conf` file and set appropriate value to the *SetJavaHome* Directive.